# New Pi 3 B+ with Octopi wireless issues

Tags: raspbian, pi-3b+, wireless, pi-b+

I recently got the B+ model and I'm trying to switch over my Octopi to it from my B model. Finally got the Pi up and running after dealing with the rainbow screen issue and now I find the wireless doesn't seem to work. The post screen says I should be able to access with http://octopi.local but doesn't include an IP. SSH doesn't connect with octopi.local as it did before either.
I'm not sure where I should go from here. I've set everything up as it was on the last setup. It appears that the wifi chip on this new Pi isn't functional.
Is there any way to check this? Is there some other code I need to look at changing for network access?

**Update from comments:**
 I was running Octopi/Raspbian on my RPI3 model B, and my intention was to just move the SD over to my RPI3 mB+. I figured out that I couldn't do that until I updated the build first before I moved it over. It loaded on the B+ but the wireless was no longer working. I plugged in an eth cable and that seemed to work ok but I need wireless to be running for this particular application.

Octopi doesn't have a gui (at least not on the Pi itself) so you can't just go to the wireless icon and choose your ssid from a list and log in. You have to go to the network file and enter it all manually. This was already done when it was initially running on the model B. I guess I just expected it to be running when I moved it over to the B+. All I did was update the software and move the SD over to the B+. I don't imagine any coding needs to be done for it to work on the B+.

Comment: "Is there some other code I need" how can we tell, because no one knows what you did. The Pi3B+ NEEDS new firmware/kernel for new networking hardware.

You could try rpi-update (although this needs to be used with caution), OR copy raspberrypi-bootloader raspberrypi-kernel from a Raspbian site (I have not tried this), OR copy the new kernels PLUS their modules from a Raspbian installation.

Comment: Do you use `Raspbian`? What means _"switch over my Octopi"_? Does you put the SD Card from `RPi 3B` into `RPi 3B+`?

Comment: Sorry for being so vague. I tend to leave out pertinent info when I get flustered....when I'm to a point where I'm asking for help, I'm usually pretty flustered.

I was running Octopi/Raspbian on my RPI3 model B, and my intention was to just move the SD over to my RPI3 mB+. I figured out that I couldn't do that until I updated the build first before I moved it over. It loaded on the B+ but the wireless was no longer working. I plugged in an eth cable and that seemed to work ok but I need wireless to be running for this particular application.

Comment: Octopi doesn't have a gui (at least not on the Pi itself) so you can't just go to the wireless icon and choose your ssid from a list and log in. You have to go to the network file and enter it all manually. This was already done when it was initially running on the model B. I guess I just expected it to be running when I moved it over to the B+. All I did was update the software and move the SD over to the B+. I don't imagine any coding needs to be done for it to work on the B+.

Comment: What Raspbian version do you use? Stretch? Buster? When wireless doesn't work please execute the commands on the RasPi `ip addr` and `ip route`, edit your question and paste the output into it.

Answer (score 1):

As you're aware, you configure OctoPi to connect to WiFi using `octopi-network.txt`.  To troubleshoot why it might not be working, you can take a look at the log of the service which controls your WiFi:

```
sudo journalctl -u ifup@wlan0.service
```

For now, though, it looks like this is a [Known Issue](https://github.com/guysoft/OctoPi/issues/505), and it mentions on the [OctoPrint webpage](https://octoprint.org/download/) that you should use the [Nightly build](http://gnethomelinux.com/OctoPi/nightly/) if you have a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+.

I suspect the largest changes are to `/boot/config.txt`.

For others in the future, it might be possible that the DNS just isn't working, so be sure to try accessing by IP vs domain `octopi.local`.